# flower automaton for L = {aa, bb, ba, baa, bba}

Tags: automata

I have been an assignment to generate flower automation for the above language.
I would like to be explained what flower automation is and how to generate it.
Also what is the connection between DFA and flower automation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the given language, this would be a probable solution.

[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ayxh.jpg)